# docker-baseimage-alpine-nginx without fpm and nginx

Tags: docker, dockerfile, s6

I'm running two containers with this image: https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-baseimage-alpine-nginx
First container is taking web requests and all is fine there, the second one however is only for queue. We feel like running nginx and php-fpm is unnecessarily eating up memory.
We want to disable nginx and php-fpm based on the environment variable CONTAINER_ROLE.
So far the only solution I've come up with is to override the root/etc/s6-overlay/s6-rc.d/svc-nginx
and root/etc/s6-overlay/s6-rc.d/svc-php-fpm and do some "if then else" there.

The drawback to this is that if and when the image updates these files, we will have to manually update our overrides.

Is there a better approach to stopping these two services?

Comment: Normally a Docker container only runs a single process.  Instead of trying to use one container with a supervisor process, can you run separate containers based on the `nginx`, `php:fpm`, and plain `php` images?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are suggesting. First thing I said in original post is "I'm running two containers".
If what you mean, is to have 2 different images, one that runs php:fpm and nginx and the other that just runs queue, then yes I could do that. But, that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Why?  This base image in particular seems to be simulating a virtual machine, with a full init system and a half-dozen processes, and it seems like using a dedicated base image for each separate process would be cleaner.  Put another way, if you have a separate image built `FROM php` that only runs the worker, then there aren't other things in the container startup that you'll need to disable.